# Javascript Templating in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Just a quick questions to all my Salesforce Developers:

Do Salesforce Lightning support Javascript templating. If yes, then how?

### From comment:

My question was to put some code like below in Ltng components:

```
<script id="president-template" type="text/template">
{{#presidents}}
<li>{{name}} ({{born}}-{{death}})</li>
{{/presidents}}
</script>
```

Here we are defining a template in JS using type="text/template". How to define this script type in Lightning component?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Lightning does support [JavaScript templating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating). There is a short example in this [Render and Preview the Contact List](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/project/quickstart-lightning-components/quickstart-lightning-components5) page. If by "how" you mean "how to I do it" you would be best to work through e.g. [Quick Start: Lightning Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/quickstart-lightning-components) to understand that.

Presumably because it is familiar to Visualforce developers, `{! ... }` is used to reference data from a template instead of e.g. `{{ ... }}`. In Visualforce the data is substituted at the server-side whereas in Lightning the data is substitured at the client-side (via JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Keith. I think you assumed JS templating by Data binding. My question was to put some code like below in Ltng components.
<script id="president-template" type="text/template"> 
 {{#presidents}}
  <li>{{name}} ({{born}}-{{death}})</li>
 {{/presidents}}
</script>

>>>  Here we are defining a template in JS using type="text/template". How to define this script type in lighting component. This was my question.

Comment: @ThisIsRSN OK. I took Wikepedia's advice on what "Javascript templating" meant... I've added your extra information to the question so others can see it and answer.